# Object uses another class Java

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

I'm just wondering if its possible to implement another class once an object has been selected from an object array? I'm creating a chess game with 3 different levels of difficulty and once the user chooses a difficulty,then the game state would change based on their selection.
The code I have for selection is:

```
Object[] options={"Easy","Medium", "Hard"};
        human=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Please Select Difficulty", "Please Select Difficulty", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[1]);
```

I have 3 classes made for the difficulties

Could I use an if statement to make this possible?

Thanks

Comment: You probably want to look into polymorphic collections.

Comment: you can provide any class to JOptionPane. and, you can specify which text will be shown to override toString function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do it like:

```
class ChessGame 
class DifficltChessGame extends ChessGame
class MediumChessGame extends ChessGame
class SimpleChessGame extends ChessGame
class ChessGameFactory {
     public static ChessGame getChessGame(String gameType) {
         switch(gameType) { //jdk7
             case "easy":
                 return new SimpleChessGame();
              ....
         }
     }
}
```

And from your code you could do something like:

```
 String[] options={"Easy","Medium", "Hard"};//use enum instead
 humanInput=...
 ChessGame game = ChessGameFactory.getChessGame(humanInput);
```

Comment: This example is, essentially, called a [Factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) (a well-known creational "Gang Of Four" pattern).